# Selecting background color to the DT table values (free selection, without any conditions) in R shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny, dt

I am new to R shiny. I am trying to find if there is a function to [
create a selection of background colors  "Add or change the background color of cells" in the DT table. I don't have any particular criteria to give background colors. I wanted the randon colors to select or change the background colors. I have this below code. Where could I implement this, Please let me know. Thank you in advance.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)

dat <- mtcars

sketch <- tags$table(
  tags$thead(
    tags$tr(
      tags$th(),
      lapply(names(dat), tags$th)
    ),
    tags$tr(
      tags$th(id = "th0"),
      tags$th(id = "th1"),
      tags$th(id = "th2"),
      tags$th(id = "th3"),
      tags$th(id = "th4"),
      tags$th(id = "th5"),
      tags$th(id = "th6"),
      tags$th(id = "th7"),
      tags$th(id = "th8"),
      tags$th(id = "th9"),
      tags$th(id = "th10"),
      tags$th(id = "th11")
    )
  )
)

js <- c(
  "function(){", 
  "  this.api().columns().every(function(i){",
  "    var column = this;",
  "    var select = $('<select multiple=\"multiple\"><option value=\"\"></option></select>')",
  "      .appendTo( $('#th'+i).empty() )", 
  "      .on('change', function(){",
  "        var vals = $('option:selected', this).map(function(index,element){",
  "          return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());",
  "        }).toArray().join('|');",
  "        column.search(vals.length > 0 ? '^('+vals+')$' : '', true, false).draw();",
  "      });",
  "    var data = column.data();",
  "    if(i == 0){",
  "      data.each(function(d, j){",
  "        select.append('<option value=\"'+d+'\">'+d+'</option>');",
  "      });",
  "    }else{",
  "      data.unique().sort().each(function(d, j){",
  "        select.append('<option value=\"'+d+'\">'+d+'</option>');",
  "      });",
  "    }",
  "    select.select2({width: '120%', closeOnSelect: false});",
  "  });",
  "}")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js")
  ),
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
   
    datatable(
      dat, container=sketch, editable = "cell", class = 'cell-border stripe', extensions = 'Buttons',
      options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = list('copy', 'pdf', 'csv', 'excel', 'print'),
        orderCellsTop = TRUE,
        initComplete = JS(js),
        columnDefs = list(
          list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")
        )
      )
  )
    
    
    
  }, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Example of color selection:

[image]

**Incorporated code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)
library(colourpicker)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
library(shinythemes)

dat <- mtcars

sketch <- tags$table(
  tags$thead(
    tags$tr(
      tags$th(),
      lapply(names(dat), tags$th)
    ),
    tags$tr(
      tags$th(id = "th0"),
      tags$th(id = "th1"),
      tags$th(id = "th2"),
      tags$th(id = "th3"),
      tags$th(id = "th4"),
      tags$th(id = "th5"),
      tags$th(id = "th6"),
      tags$th(id = "th7"),
      tags$th(id = "th8"),
      tags$th(id = "th9"),
      tags$th(id = "th10"),
      tags$th(id = "th11")
    )
  )
)


js <- c(
  "function(){", 
  "  this.api().columns().every(function(i){",
  "    var column = this;",
  "    var select = $('<select multiple=\"multiple\"><option value=\"\"></option></select>')",
  "      .appendTo( $('#th'+i).empty() )", 
  "      .on('change', function(){",
  "        var vals = $('option:selected', this).map(function(index,element){",
  "          return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());",
  "        }).toArray().join('|');",
  "        column.search(vals.length > 0 ? '^('+vals+')$' : '', true, false).draw();",
  "      });",
  "    var data = column.data();",
  "    if(i == 0){",
  "      data.each(function(d, j){",
  "        select.append('<option value=\"'+d+'\">'+d+'</option>');",
  "      });",
  "    }else{",
  "      data.unique().sort().each(function(d, j){",
  "        select.append('<option value=\"'+d+'\">'+d+'</option>');",
  "      });",
  "    }",
  "    select.select2({width: '120%', closeOnSelect: false});",
  "  });",
  "}")


ca  <- c(
  "table.on('click', 'td', function(e) {",
  "  const $cell = table.cell(this).nodes().to$();",
  "  const RGB = $cell.css('background-color');",
  "  const cellColor = '#' + RGB.match(/\\d+/g).map(x => (+x).toString(16).padStart(2,0)).join``",
  "  const selectedColor = $('#color').val().toLowerCase();",
  "  const color = cellColor == selectedColor ? '' : selectedColor;",
  "  $cell.css('background-color', color);",
  "});"
)


ui <- fluidPage(HTML(""),theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                tags$head(
                  tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css"),
                  tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js")
                ),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    colourInput(
                      "color", 
                      "Choose background color",
                      palette = "limited",
                      closeOnClick = TRUE
                    )
                  ),
                  
                  
                  mainPanel(
                    br(),
                    DTOutput("dtable")
                  )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    
    datatable(
      dat, container=sketch, editable = "cell", class = 'cell-border stripe', extensions = 'Buttons',
      options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = list('copy', 'pdf', 'csv', 'excel', 'print'),
                     orderCellsTop = TRUE,
                     selection = "none", 
                     callback = JS(js),
                     callback = JS(ca),
                     columnDefs = list(
                       list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")
        )
      )
    )
    
  }, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You mean an unique color for all cells?

Comment: Yes, If I want to select blue or red or yellow, I would like to have a selection (as the attached image) and able to select any color a background to any value in the DT table,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(colourpicker)

CSS <- function(tableid, color) {
  sprintf("#%s tr {background-color: %s;}", tableid, color)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      colourInput(
        "color", 
        "Choose background color"
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("css"),
      DTOutput("dtable")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["css"]] <- renderUI({
    tags$style(HTML(CSS("dtable", input[["color"]])))
  })
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

## Edit: color for a single cell

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(colourpicker)

CSS <- function(tableid, color, i, j) {
  sprintf(
    "#%s tr:nth-child(%d) td:nth-child(%d) {background-color: %s;}", 
    tableid, i, j, color
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("row", "Choose row", value = 1, min = 1),
      numericInput("col", "Choose column", value = 1, min = 1),
      colourInput(
        "color", 
        "Choose background color"
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("css"),
      DTOutput("dtable")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["css"]] <- renderUI({
    tags$style(HTML(
      CSS("dtable", input[["color"]], input[["row"]], input[["col"]])
    ))
  })
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

## Edit: color on click

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(colourpicker)

CSS <- function(tableid, color, i, j) {
  sprintf(
    "#%s tr:nth-child(%d) td:nth-child(%d) {background-color: %s;}", 
    tableid, i, j, color
  )
}

callback <- c(
  "table.on('click', 'tbody', function(e) {",
  "  const cell = e.target.closest('td');",
  "  if(!cell) {return;} // Quit, not clicked on a cell",
  "  const row = cell.parentElement;",
  "  const i = row.rowIndex;",
  "  const j = cell.cellIndex + 1;",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('cell', {'row': i, 'col': j});",
  "});"
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      colourInput(
        "color", 
        "Choose background color",
        palette = "limited"
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("css"),
      br(),
      DTOutput("dtable")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["css"]] <- renderUI({
    cell <- req(input[["cell"]])
    tags$style(HTML(
      CSS("dtable", input[["color"]], cell[["row"]], cell[["col"]])
    ))
  })
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris, 
      selection = "none",
      callback = JS(callback)
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

---

## Edit: multiple cells coloring and 'undo' feature

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(colourpicker)


callback <- c(
  "table.on('click', 'td', function(e) {",
  "  const $cell = table.cell(this).nodes().to$();",
  "  const RGB = $cell.css('background-color');",
  "  const cellColor = '#' + RGB.match(/\\d+/g).map(x => (+x).toString(16).padStart(2,0)).join``",
  "  const selectedColor = $('#color').val().toLowerCase();",
  "  const color = cellColor == selectedColor ? '' : selectedColor;",
  "  $cell.css('background-color', color);",
  "});"
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      colourInput(
        "color", 
        "Choose background color",
        palette = "limited",
        closeOnClick = TRUE
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      br(),
      DTOutput("dtable")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris, 
      selection = "none",
      callback = JS(callback)
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mr. Stéphane Laurent, I am looking for something else. I want to select a particular value in a column and apply background color to it. The above code colors entire row.

Comment: @KApril So why did you answer "yes" when I asked "an unique color for all cells?"? Well, see my edit and tell me what.

Comment: Hi Mr. Stéphane Laurent, sorry for the misunderstanding. Your solution looks great! but is there a way to do it witout having selection for columns and rows. Because I might have 1000's of rows with 24 columns in my data, it would be difficult to select the row and column. If there is a way to just click on the cell and make a background color selection, that would be really great!

Comment: @KApril Doable - take a look at my edit. But you probably want to have the possibility to assign a color to several cells.... Hmm let me think about that.

Comment: @KApril Edited again. The last solution is really nice.

Comment: Hi Mr. Stéphane Laurent, that looks very nice, but when I go to the next entries and come back to the 1st 1 to 10 entries the selected colors are gone. Is there a way the colors remain even when the table rows are navigated? Even to download the table into excel for the selected colors to remain?

Comment: @KApril Ah yes, put `server=FALSE` in `renderDT` and that will work.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Stéphane Laurent. Now I will try to incorporate this code in the earlier code, that was also from you. I want to try this myself without posting this again here. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hello Mr. Stéphane Laurent, I have tried to combine both the codes (Please see updated code with the title "incorporated code" the color selection appears in the sidebarpanel but it is not working when I want to give  a background color to the cells. Could you please help me?

Comment: @KApril You didn't include the JavaScript code for the callback (`callback = JS(js)` - also change the name `js` because it is already used - it's `JS(callback)`).

Comment: Hello Mr. Stéphane Laurent, Earlier I have combined both the callbacks to js but now I separated and called both the callbacks in the code but still the background coloring is not working. I am confused where is the mistake I am making. Could you please help?

Comment: @KApril you didn't take the last version...

Comment: Hello Mr. Stéphane Laurent, sorry my bad, I have updated code but still I can't use the background colors.

Comment: @KApril Re-read your code please :-(

Comment: Hello Mr. Stéphane Laurent, I am blind or stupid,. I don't really see what is wrong with the code. But I am thinking I am not correct the way I use the callback. Please tell me where it needs the fix.

Comment: I think you are referring to initComplete. When I changed code to  ```initComplete = JS(js) ```  it is working but when I add ```callback = JS(cs)``` it is not working.

Comment: @KApril `callback` must not be in `options`

Comment: I have changed the code by moving options below the callback
  ```initComplete  = JS(js), callback = JS(ca), options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = list('copy', 'pdf', 'csv', 'excel', 'print'),  columnDefs = list(list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")))) ``` but it gives error ```unused arguments```

Comment: I never said that `initComplete` must not be in `options` @KApril

Comment: scratching head and losing confidence :-(

Comment: yes I got it ```datatable(
      dat, callback = JS(ca), selection = "none", container=sketch, editable = "cell", class = 'cell-border stripe', extensions = 'Buttons',
      options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = list('copy', 'pdf', 'csv', 'excel', 'print'),
                     orderCellsTop = TRUE,
                      
                     initComplete  = JS(js),
                     columnDefs = list(
                       list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")
        )
      )
    )```

Comment: thank you so much Mr. Stéphane Laurent :-)

Comment: Hello, Mr. Mr. Stéphane Laurent, I have another question. I am trying to export the DT table from R shiny to the excel sheet. When I am exporting it is ignoring the background colors. Is there a way R shiny could export the table along with the background colors as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76579460/r-shiny-dt-table-ignoring-background-color-while-exporting-to-excel-sheet