# R shiny DT table ignoring background color while exporting to excel sheet

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, dt

I am trying to export the data from R shiny DT table to the excel sheet after selecting background color to some of the cells in the DT table. But the code exports only the data from the DT table but not exporting along with the background colors selected of the cells.

Could someone please help me what changes need to be made to the code. ANy help is much appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)
library(colourpicker)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
library(shinythemes)

dat <- mtcars

sketch <- tags$table(
  tags$thead(
    tags$tr(
      tags$th(),
      lapply(names(dat), tags$th)
    ),
    tags$tr(
      tags$th(id = "th0"),
      tags$th(id = "th1"),
      tags$th(id = "th2"),
      tags$th(id = "th3"),
      tags$th(id = "th4"),
      tags$th(id = "th5"),
      tags$th(id = "th6"),
      tags$th(id = "th7"),
      tags$th(id = "th8"),
      tags$th(id = "th9"),
      tags$th(id = "th10"),
      tags$th(id = "th11")
    )
  )
)


js <- c(
  "function(){", 
  "  this.api().columns().every(function(i){",
  "    var column = this;",
  "    var select = $('<select multiple=\"multiple\"><option value=\"\"></option></select>')",
  "      .appendTo( $('#th'+i).empty() )", 
  "      .on('change', function(){",
  "        var vals = $('option:selected', this).map(function(index,element){",
  "          return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());",
  "        }).toArray().join('|');",
  "        column.search(vals.length > 0 ? '^('+vals+')$' : '', true, false).draw();",
  "      });",
  "    var data = column.data();",
  "    if(i == 0){",
  "      data.each(function(d, j){",
  "        select.append('<option value=\"'+d+'\">'+d+'</option>');",
  "      });",
  "    }else{",
  "      data.unique().sort().each(function(d, j){",
  "        select.append('<option value=\"'+d+'\">'+d+'</option>');",
  "      });",
  "    }",
  "    select.select2({width: '120%', closeOnSelect: false});",
  "  });",
  "}")


ca  <- c(
  "table.on('click', 'td', function(e) {",
  "  const $cell = table.cell(this).nodes().to$();",
  "  const RGB = $cell.css('background-color');",
  "  const cellColor = '#' + RGB.match(/\\d+/g).map(x => (+x).toString(16).padStart(2,0)).join``",
  "  const selectedColor = $('#color').val().toLowerCase();",
  "  const color = cellColor == selectedColor ? '' : selectedColor;",
  "  $cell.css('background-color', color);",
  "});"
)


ui <- fluidPage(HTML(""),
                tags$head(
                  tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css"),
                  tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js")
                ),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    colourInput(
                      "color", 
                      "Choose background color",
                      palette = "limited",
                      closeOnClick = TRUE
                    )
                  ),
                  
                  
                  mainPanel(
                    br(),
                    DTOutput("dtable")
                  )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    
    datatable(
      dat, callback = JS(ca),  selection = "none", container=sketch, editable = "cell",  class = 'cell-border stripe', extensions = 'Buttons', 
      options = list(dom = 'BPrlftip', buttons = list('copy', 'pdf', 'csv', 'excel', 'print'), 
                     orderCellsTop = TRUE,
                     
                     initComplete  = JS(js),
                     columnDefs = list(
                       list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")
                     )
      )
    )
    
  }, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Incorporated code**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)
library(colourpicker)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
library(shinythemes)

dat <- mtcars

sketch <- tags$table(
  tags$thead(
    tags$tr(
      tags$th(),
      lapply(names(dat), tags$th)
    ),
    tags$tr(
      tags$th(id = "th0"),
      tags$th(id = "th1"),
      tags$th(id = "th2"),
      tags$th(id = "th3"),
      tags$th(id = "th4"),
      tags$th(id = "th5"),
      tags$th(id = "th6"),
      tags$th(id = "th7"),
      tags$th(id = "th8"),
      tags$th(id = "th9"),
      tags$th(id = "th10"),
      tags$th(id = "th11")
    )
  )
)


js <- c(
  "function(){", 
  "  this.api().columns().every(function(i){",
  "    var column = this;",
  "    var select = $('<select multiple=\"multiple\"><option value=\"\"></option></select>')",
  "      .appendTo( $('#th'+i).empty() )", 
  "      .on('change', function(){",
  "        var vals = $('option:selected', this).map(function(index,element){",
  "          return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());",
  "        }).toArray().join('|');",
  "        column.search(vals.length > 0 ? '^('+vals+')$' : '', true, false).draw();",
  "      });",
  "    var data = column.data();",
  "    if(i == 0){",
  "      data.each(function(d, j){",
  "        select.append('<option value=\"'+d+'\">'+d+'</option>');",
  "      });",
  "    }else{",
  "      data.unique().sort().each(function(d, j){",
  "        select.append('<option value=\"'+d+'\">'+d+'</option>');",
  "      });",
  "    }",
  "    select.select2({width: '120%', closeOnSelect: false});",
  "  });",
  "}")


ca  <- c(
  "table.on('click', 'td', function(e) {",
  "  const $cell = table.cell(this).nodes().to$();",
  "  const RGB = $cell.css('background-color');",
  "  const cellColor = '#' + RGB.match(/\\d+/g).map(x => (+x).toString(16).padStart(2,0)).join``",
  "  const selectedColor = $('#color').val().toLowerCase();",
  "  const color = cellColor == selectedColor ? '' : selectedColor;",
  "  $cell.css('background-color', color);",
  "});"
)

customize <- "
function(xlsx, button, table) {
 
  const LETTERS = 
    ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];

  var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
 
  var row = 0;
  const num_columns = table.columns().count();
 
  $('row', sheet).each(function(x) {
    if(x > 1) {
      for(let i=0; i < num_columns; i++) {
        const $cell = $(table.cell(':eq('+row+')', i).node()); 
        const RGB = $cell.css('background-color');
        const cellColor = '#' + RGB.match(/\\d+/g).map(x => (+x).toString(16).padStart(2,0)).join``;
        if(cellColor == '#ff0000') {
          $('row:eq(' + (x) + ') c[r^=' + (LETTERS[i]) + ']', sheet).attr('s', '10');
        } else if(cellColor == '#00ff00') {
          $('row:eq(' + (x) + ') c[r^=' + (LETTERS[i]) + ']', sheet).attr('s', '15');
        }
      }
      row++;
    }
  });
}"


ui <- fluidPage(HTML(""),
                tags$head(
                  tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css"),
                  tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js")
                ),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    colourInput(
                      "color", 
                      "Choose background color",
                      palette = "limited",
                      closeOnClick = TRUE
                    )
                  ),
                  
                  
                  mainPanel(
                    br(),
                    DTOutput("dtable")
                  )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat, callback = JS(ca),  selection = "none", container=sketch, editable = "cell",  class = 'cell-border stripe', extensions = 'Buttons', 
      options = list(dom = 'BPrlftip', buttons = list(list(
                                                 extend = "excel",
                                                 text = "Save XLSX",
                                                 customize = JS(customize))), 
                     orderCellsTop = TRUE,
                     initComplete  = JS(js),
                     columnDefs = list(
                       list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")
                     )))
  }, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has to use the `customize` option of the Excel button. That's a bit annoying, because each color corresponds to a special Excel code and we would have to list all possibilities. Here I started to implement it for red and green only.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(colourpicker)

callback <- c(
  "table.on('click', 'td', function(e) {",
  "  const $cell = table.cell(this).nodes().to$();",
  "  const RGB = $cell.css('background-color');",
  "  const cellColor = '#' + RGB.match(/\\d+/g).map(x => (+x).toString(16).padStart(2,0)).join``",
  "  const selectedColor = $('#color').val().toLowerCase();",
  "  const color = cellColor == selectedColor ? '' : selectedColor;",
  "  $cell.css('background-color', color);",
  "});"
)


customize <- "
function(xlsx, button, table) {
 
  const LETTERS = 
    ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];

  var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
 
  var row = 0;
  const num_columns = table.columns().count();
 
  $('row', sheet).each(function(x) {
    if(x > 1) {
      for(let i=0; i < num_columns; i++) {
        const $cell = $(table.cell(':eq('+row+')', i).node()); 
        const RGB = $cell.css('background-color');
        const cellColor = '#' + RGB.match(/\\d+/g).map(x => (+x).toString(16).padStart(2,0)).join``;
        if(cellColor == '#ff0000') {
          $('row:eq(' + (x) + ') c[r^=' + (LETTERS[i]) + ']', sheet).attr('s', '10');
        } else if(cellColor == '#00ff00') {
          $('row:eq(' + (x) + ') c[r^=' + (LETTERS[i]) + ']', sheet).attr('s', '15');
        }
      }
      row++;
    }
  });
}"
  

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      colourInput(
        "color", 
        "Choose background color",
        palette = "limited",
        closeOnClick = TRUE
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      br(),
      DTOutput("dtable")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris, 
      extensions = "Buttons",
      selection = "none",
      callback = JS(callback),
      options = list(
        dom = "Bfrtip",
        buttons = list(
          list(
            extend = "excel",
            text = "Save XLSX",
            customize = JS(customize)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Mr. Stéphane Laurent, thank you again. I am not sure why the code is not working for me. It still doesn't export the background colors. I have updated my incorporated code above.

Comment: @KApril Have you used only red (#ff0000) and green (#00ff00)? That works only for these colors.

Comment: Hello Mr. Stéphane Laurent, Is there a way to make all colors work?

Comment: @KApril you have to continue the `else if(cellColor == xxxx) { ... }` using these codes: https://www.excelsupersite.com/what-are-the-56-colorindex-colors-in-excel/

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Stéphane Laurent!!